# Echoing data from OOPHP

Tags: class

I'm trying to get my head around OOPHP and have sort-of figured out classes, why they're useful and how to work with them through doing some tutorials. I've found myself struggling to output certain parts of the code.

I have:

```
    protected static $_instance = null;     
    protected $_pdo = null
    protected function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/database'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
            $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->_pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            echo "There was an error connecting to the database.";
            exit();
        }           
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }

        return self::$_instance;

    }
```

To test the modularity of OOPHP I downloaded a pagination class. One of the requirements is to set the 'db_handle'. Procedurally you would say something like `$handle = new PDO('mysql:host=...')` and thus `db_handle => $handle`

Of course in this case the handle has been abstracted to a constructor function. How is it possible to echo out the equivalent of a "$handle" variable?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a Singleton here? You likely don't want a singleton here. It's kind of an anti pattern :)

Comment: Why would it be anti-pattern here? He's clearly using it to create a static DAL instance to run queries against. It's not like he needs to construct DALs all day long.

Comment: I'm just using this to figure things out in OOPHP. I don't plan on running this into production or anything :)